# echo color coding stopped working in mountain lion

Tags: terminal

The following produced text with different color on terminal in Lion, but not in Mountain Lion. Why? What can be done to echo in color on Mountain Lion?

```
echo -e "Some text \e[0;32m in color \e[0m no more color";
```

In mountain Lion it just prints as if -e wasn't given as an argument to echo.

Comment: Strangely, man echo does not mention the -e flag, even though the -e flag works. At least for \n

Comment: The manage for *echo* describes the `/bin/echo` external command, not the *echo* that is built into the shell that you happen to be using (e.g. the one named in the `#!` line at the top of your script). You need to consult the manpage for the shell that you are using (probably *bash*) to see what options its internal *echo* supports.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As described in the [Application Usage section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_16) of the [POSIX description of the *echo* command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), the `-n` option and escape sequences are not very portable (due to different support in the various branches of the Unix family tree).

The `printf` command (which, like *echo*, is also builtin to most shells, and available as an external command) is more reliably standardized (though the syntax is not the same; e.g. you need to watch for `%` in the first argument, and multiple arguments are not automatically joined with a space):

```
printf 'Some text \e[0;32m in color \e[0m no more color\n'

printf '%s \e[0;32m%s\e[0m %s\n' 'Some text' 'in color' 'no more color'
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, accepted your answer since it was better than the one I found.

Answer (score 15):

The problem was that the escape code \e has been removed in mountain lion's version of echo. 
Change \e to \033 and it will work.

Comment: This site holds true for Yosemite, cheers much appreciated..

Comment: Holds true for Sierra as well, despite `man bash` listing `\e` as a valid escape.

Answer (score 4):

A reliable way to do this is through tput:

```
RED=`tput setaf 1`
GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
NOCOLOR=`tput sgr0`

echo "Some text ${RED}in red color${NOCOLOR} no more color"
```

Comment: This is a very clear and clever way to setup colors!